# What should be the regex for strings?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex for strings -

```
c190_12_1-10
c129
abc_1-90
```

to separate to -

```
['c190_12_', '1', '10']
['c', '129']
['abc_', '1', '90']
```

So far I've came up with `(\D+)(\d+)-?(\d+)?`

But, it doesn't work for all combinations. What I am missing here?

Comment: Which ones doesn't it work for?

Comment: Can you explain the rules of your split?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte If it has range - for eg, c190_12_1-10 - I want to split it as prefix->start->end.

Otherwise, in case of c129 - split it as prefix->start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
items = ['c190_12_1-10', 'c129', 'abc_1-90']
reg = re.compile(r'^(.+?)(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$')

for item in items:
   m = reg.match(item)
   print m.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you do and don't want to match, but this might work for you:

```
(?:(\w+)(\d+)-|([a-z]+))(\d+)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/uA3eZ4

The secret here was working backwards form the end, where it always seems to be the same condition. Then using the conditionals and the non-capture group, you end up with the result you've shown.

Comment: In case of c129, it groups just 129 and not [c, 129]